# Perturbing initial condition and perturbing ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, perturbation-theory

Is perturbing the initial condition $x=x_0$ to $x=x_0+\delta$ for a non-autonomous system

$\dot{x}=f(x,t)$

which has zero as equilibra, same as perturbing the ode itself

$\dot{x}=f(x,t)+g(x,t)$

with $\parallel g(x,t) \parallel < \delta_1$ for some $\delta_1 > 0$. In other words if we perturb the initial condition can we obtain a perturbed ode with bounded perturbation term and the otherway? If not what other condition is necessary for the same?

Comment: Generically no, at least not without using delta functions. By comparison, doing this with delta functions is quite standard.

Comment: The solution $y$ with initial value $y_0=x_0+δ$ can be represented as $y=u+δ$ where $u$ is a solution of $\dot u=f(u+δ,t)\approx f(u,t)+δf_x(u,t)$ and initial value $u_0=x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Think of

$$
\dot x + a x = 0
$$

with general solution

$$
x = C_0 e^{-a t}
$$

As can be seen the initial conditions are independent from the differential equation structure.  then

$$
x+\delta x = C_0 e^{-at}+\delta C_0 e^{-at}
$$